# How to create custom language for TextToSpeech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I need to use Indian-English or Hindi (Mother-tongue) language for TTS in Android.
But I didn't found any hint or source code related to Creating a custom Language.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check if the TSS API  is installed in your emulator device using the following.

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);


mTts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.INDIA)); //try Locale.INDIA or Locale.INDIAN_ENGLISH or Locale.HINDI as I have not used Indian languages or Indian English dialect in it before
```

which will return  `TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE` to indicate that preferences for such a language are installed and available. Then use the following for a test.

```
String myText1 = "Did you sleep well?";
String myText2 = "I hope so, because it's time to wake up.";
mTts.speak(myText1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
mTts.speak(myText2, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

More info is available [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html)

**EDIT** To check if the language is available on your phone, use `getAvailableLocales()` as follows

```
   Locale loc = new Locale("en");
   Log.i("-------------",Arrays.toString(loc.getAvailableLocales()));
```

It should show results in your Log output

The language codes are two-letter lowercase ISO language codes (such as "en") as defined by ISO 639-1. The country codes are two-letter uppercase ISO country codes (such as "US") as defined by ISO 3166-1.

Comment: Thanks...But how to check whether this language is available or not?

Comment: Sure..As a user you should avoid posting gratuity using "thank you" and instead tick check the answer that you find helpful.