# Implementing my TTS project using own language

Tags: java, text-to-speech, freetts

I have a problem with my android project. i want to implement my text-to-speech software using my own language "Bangla/Bengali". i need to know how can i do that task? if there is a very effective solution,please let me know about that.

Comment: It's not a trivial problem.  You need to be able to break every word down into phonemes, then output the phonemes via the speaker.  It really is the type of app that needs a full team, including computational linguists.  You're best off looking for an existing solution and installing it on the phone.

Comment: Before create your own, verify if it exists 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664206/how-to-create-custom-language-for-texttospeech

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks.But can you give me some useful references that can help me to make me successful. i'm trying this with a few words. actually a project simply can translate into voice in my desire language. And um trying to create this app. just a beginning.